# getting an iterable output from a telnet client in python

Tags: python

I am trying to write a script to perform validation checks on a network device (router,switch). I am using telnet to send commands to the device. I store the output of the command telnetobject.read_until(prompt) into a file and then run some validation checks over the stored output by iterating over it one line at a time.
Is there a way to iterate over the output without storing it in a file? the issue is the read_until option gives the output in one string and the output of the device i am trying to test has an output in a tabular form which does not have a consistent delimiter on each line.

This is an example:
import telnetlib

```
tn=telnetlib.Telnet('ip address')
pwd='password'
uid='userid'

tn.read_until("login: ")
tn.write(uid + "\n")
tn.read_until("Password:")
tn.write(pwd +'\n')
tn.read_until(">",5)
tn.write('port statistics show' + '\n')
op1=tn.read_until("*>",5)
with open ('stattest-temp.txt','w') as stat:
 stat.write(op1)
```

above code was to get a particular output and store it in a file
below code is to iterate over the output..problem is it is in a tabular form and starts with multiple '_ _ _' characters and each line in the table has different number of elements if you split it using a delimiter, hence it becomes difficult to iterate over output from tn.read_until as it is all one giant string'

```
with open ('stattest-temp.txt','r') as f:


 for line_no,line in enumerate(f):
   if line_no>5:
    if '+---------------------------------+----------------+-----------+-----------+------------+\r' in line:
     break
    else:
     x=line[:-1].split("|")
     #print x
     x1=x[1].strip()
     x2=x[2].strip()
     x3=x[3].strip()
     x4=x[4].strip()
     x5=x[5].strip()
     if x4 =="YES":
       print x1,x4
       print 'Traffic loss observed'

     elif x4=="No":
      print "session recovered"
```

I am looking for a way to do part 2 of the above code without having to write the output to a file

Comment: Can You share the code, or the problem you are facing.

Comment: i have tried to add as much detail as i can using the above example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you split the output string on newline characters, this should replicate the effect of saving to a file and the iterating through lines. Basically set this before your `for` loop:

```
 f = op1.split('\n')

 for line_no,line in enumerate(f):
   if line_no>5:
    if '+---------------------------------+----------------+-----------+-----------+------------+\r' in line:
     break
    else:
     x=line[:-1].split("|")
     #print x
     x1=x[1].strip()
     x2=x[2].strip()
     x3=x[3].strip()
     x4=x[4].strip()
     x5=x[5].strip()
     if x4 =="YES":
       print x1,x4
       print 'Traffic loss observed'

     elif x4=="No":
      print "session recovered"
```

Comment: seems fair..but the issue is the there are multiple columns in the output so if i split on newline i will end up with values from all columns as a single element including the delimiter '|'. it becomes tedious to match to expected output as number of rows increases .

Comment: no keep your code as it is, and still split by '|' in the loop

Comment: seems to have done the trick! feel so dumb..it was staring me right in the face..Thanks!

Comment: Lol no probs glad i could help.